# How to reduce the distance (space) between lines in the Legend in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, legend, space, lines, zedgraph

How to reduce the distance (space) between lines in the Legend in ZedGraph like in photo marked with red arrows?

[image]

Comment: See around [Legend.cs and _tmpSize](https://github.com/ZedGraph/ZedGraph/blob/master/source/ZedGraph/Legend.cs#L123)